# Integrating $\cos^3(x)$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

My attempt at integrating $\cos^3(x)$:

$$\begin{align}\;\int \cos^3x\mathrm{d}x &= \int \cos^2x  \cos x \mathrm{d}x
\\&= \int(1 - \sin^2 x) \cos x \mathrm{d}x
\\&= \int \cos x dx - \int \sin^2x \cos x \mathrm{d}x 
\\&= \sin x - \frac {1}{3}\sin^3x + C\end{align}$$

My question is how does integrating $\sin^2(x) \cos x $ become $\frac {1}{3}\sin^3(x) + C$? What mathematical process is being done? Why does the $\cos x$ disappear?

Comment: you can see it as a guess - just differentiate $\sin(x)^3$ using the chain rule and see for yourself that it works ($[f(x)^3)]' = 3f(x)^2 f'(x)$)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you let $u = \sin x$, then $du = \cos x \ dx,$ and 
$\int \sin^2x \cos x \ dx $ becomes $$\int u^2 du  = \frac{1}{3} u^3 + C.$$

Then you substitute $u=\sin x$ back in.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that applying the chain rule to $\frac{1}{3}\sin^3(x)$ yields $\sin^2(x)\cos(x)$. Indeed you have $\int\sin^2(x)\cos(x)\,dx=\int\sin^2(x)\,d(\sin(x))=\frac{1}{3}\sin^3(x)+c$

Answer (score 0):

If by $\sin(x)^2$ you mean $(\sin(x))^2$, we could follow
$$\cos(2x)=\cos(x)^2-\sin(x)^2=1-2\sin(x)^2$$
to have
$$\int \sin(x)^2 = \int \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2}\cos(2x) = \frac{1}{2}x-\frac{1}{4}\sin(2x)$$
Then go ahead and use integration by parts we done.

Comment: yea indeed @andrey gives you a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int\sin^2x\cos x\,dx$$
Let $u=\sin x$. Therefore $du=\cos x\,dx$, giving
$$I=\int u^2du$$
$$I=\frac{u^3}{3}+C=\frac{\sin^3x}{3}+C$$

Answer (score 0):

You can use this bit of trickery.

$\cos 3x = 4\cos^3 x - 3\cos x\\
\cos^3x = \frac 14 \cos 3x + \frac 34\cos x$

And that is easy to integrate.

But, to your actual question. $\int \sin^2x\cos x \ dx$

let $u = \sin x, du = \cos x$

$\int u^2 \ du$